# A website tells me my password is compromised, does this imply the website is also insecure?

Tags: html, security, passwords, password-hash

I recently logged into a website (student run club website which stores event and participant information).

After successfully logging in the following message appears and follows me around for the rest of my time on the site:

> You are using an insecure password. The password that you entered has
>   been exposed in at least one data breach.
>
> How do you know my password is insecure? This password appears in a
>   [database of known passwords](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords). Hackers may use this password to try to
>   break into your accounts.

While I appreciate the notification that my password was compromised (and should know better and will change and stop reusing passwords etc etc) I now worry about the overall security of this site.

I don't know a terrible lot about web dev but my naive assumption, given this message and the fact that it appears *after* log in, is that my password must have been stored in plain text for them to be able to check it against a database. Is this correct? Or is there some clever secure way this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you are receiving a notification from the site doesn't mean that your passwords are being stored in plaintext. Whatever website you are using can use your password in the "Have I Been Pwned" API before encrypting them. This of course doesn't necessarily mean that they are encrypting them as there isn't really a surefire way to know how they are storing your passwords without possibly contacting the owner or if you were to receive an email at a later date with your password in it.

You can read up on the API for password checking here [haveibeenpwned.com/API](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3) or you can check for the website you are using in this list here [haveibeenpwned.com/API/Consumers](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/Consumers).